# Why does User Account Control ask for permission every time I turn on my computer

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

This shows up whenever I turn on my computer.  I have tried clicking yes and no but it keeps showing up every time I turn on my computer.

Is this a bug and is there any way to fix it?  I'm using windows 10 pro.

[image]

Comment: You have an entry in your registry, that is automatically starting ASUS software, that requires elevated permissions.  **I suggest you uninstall that software to avoid this prompt.**  The name of the program, is indicated within the prompt, it might be bundled with other software.

Comment: Also search that software in scheduled task.

Comment: use [autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to disable starting of this ASUS tool

Answer (score 0):

UAC prompt every time you log into Windows account indicates that some application running at startup is requesting these permissions (in this case Asus' software).

The easiest way to check which applications are started automatically is to go into Task Manager and select Startup tab. There you can see which applications are loaded and if any looks suspect. Worst-case scenario, just disable a few suspected applications at the time to see when UAC prompts stop.

As prompt on the picture you linked indicates at least one application that is causing this issue (ledcontrolservice), I would proceed disabling that one first and seeing if prompt goes away or there are further offenders.

If this application has to run on startup, I would advice filing a bug with application's manufacturer.

Comment: The program isn't listed in the startup tab.